# How to set icons in Android application

Tags: android, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A grid layout of icon/text buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046320/a-grid-layout-of-icon-text-buttons)

I am making an Android apps which will have 9 icons and I want to arrange them in 3*3 row and column. How to do it that it fills entire screen on any Android phone without worrying of dimensions.

Comment: use grid layout for achieving the same..

Comment: [Best Tutorial with Sample code](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/) also [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: atleast accept one answer as right..

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use LinearLayouts: one main vertical LinearLayout containing three horizontal LinearLayouts, each one containing three icons.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:background="#FFFFFF" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_1"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_1" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 1" 
       ></Button>
<Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_2"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_2" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 2" 
       ></Button>
<Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_3"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_3" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 3" 
       ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_4"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_4" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 4" 
       ></Button>
 <Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_5"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_5" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Icon 5" 
       ></Button>
 <Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_6"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_6" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 6" 
       ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_7"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_7" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 7" 
       ></Button>
 <Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_8"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_8" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 8" 
       ></Button>
 <Button 
       android:id="@+id/icon_9"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_9" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="15sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:text="Icon 9" 
       ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the result:

[image: screen icons]

Comment: Wouldn't you need a layout_weight property for this to work regardless of image size?

Comment: @Cruceo Yes, you're right...I meant layout_weight in place of layout_gravity! Vote up for your comment! Thanks!

Comment: Both gridlayout and above example are leaving space if size of image is small...